# lockInterruptibly() state if the lock is not available

Tags: java, multithreading

According to Java 7 docs for lockInterruptibly(), if the lock is not available then the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant ... ...

What exactly is meant by the statement: "current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant"? Does it mean that the current thread goes from RUNNABLE to BLOCKED state?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that's the case, but I think RUNNABLE and BLOCKED are implementation details of the JVM. What exactly is your concern, here? It's not spinning, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I just want to make sure that the current thread goes to BLOCKED state if the lock is not available. The doc doesn't say it clearly.. Thanks

Comment: If you want to make sure, then try it and see.  Nothing we can say is more definitive than what you find in the docs + experimental observation.

Comment: I tried it and surprisingly the status changed to WAITING instead of BLOCKED. When a synchronized block was used instead of Lock, the status changed to BLOCKED as expected.

Comment: Makes sense. The docs for State say `BLOCKED` means "a thread that is blocked waiting for a monitor lock is in this state." The java.util.concurrent classes tend to not be backed by Object's synchronized, wait, and notify methods/keywords since they don't support try-acquisition or interrupts.